# Any DIV inside tab content can not appear

Tags: jquery, css, class, html, tabs

I used the simple tab jquery code from the web to show some changing content :

i put this code in the HEAD tag of my html page:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1-9-1.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#tabs div').hide();   //hide
          $('#tabs div:first').show();   //show
          $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
          $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
               $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
               $(this).parent().addClass('active');
               var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
               $('#tabs div').hide();    //hide
               $(currentTab).show();    //show
               return false;
               });
    });
</script>
```

and some rules in my CSS file:

```
/*TAB MEDIA k-enkripsi*/
.tab-wrapper {  background:#fcf;
  width: 768px; height:885px; bottom:0;
  margin:0 auto;
}

/*  TAB WRAP CONTENT    */
#tabs { 
  width: 100%; height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*  TAB content yg berubah2   */
#tabs div {
    width: 100%; height:150px;
  margin:0px; 
  clear: both;
}

h3 {
  font:18px "scada-bold"; color:#f08435;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  position:relative; float:left;
  text-align:left;
  margin:20px auto 20px;
}

.tab-img {
  width: 768px; height:465px; background: red;
}

.for-tab {
    float: right; 
    width:100%; height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:left !important;
    bottom:0;
    font: 16px "scada-regular" !important; color:white !important;
}

#tabs ul li a {
position: relative; float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*  PAGINATION TAB menu navigator */
#tabs ul { 
  position: relative; float: left; left:-38px;
  width:100%; height: 35px; margin-top: 30px;
}
#tabs li { background: #AEAEAE; display: inline;
  width: 30px; height: 34px;  margin-right: 38px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  list-style: none; 
  font:17px "melbourne-regular"; color: white;

}
#tabs li, #tabs li a {
  float: left;  
    text-align: center;
  padding-left:7px;
}
#tabs ul li.active {
  background: #f08435;  
}
#tabs ul li.active a {
  color: white;
}
```

and the last put this in HTML page to show the content tab:

```
<!-- TabMedia-enkripsi1 -->
        <div class="tab-wrapper">        
            <div id="tabs">
                <div id="tab-1" class="animated fadeIn">
                    <div class="tab-img"></div>
                    <p class="for-tab">Lorem satu ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div id="tab-2" class="animated fadeIn">
                    <div class="tab-img"></div>
                    <p class="for-tab">Lorem dua ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                </div>

                <div id="tab-3" class="animated fadeIn">
                    <div class="tab-img"></div>
                    <p class="for-tab">Lorem tiga ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div id="tab-4" class="animated fadeIn">
                    <div class="tab-img"></div>
                    <p class="for-tab">Lorem empat ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                </div>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tab-1">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab-2">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab-3">3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab-4">4</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>  <!-- tabs -->          
        </div> <!-- tab-wrapper -->
```

i tested in browser Safari, Firefox, but the CLASS 'tab-img' doesn't appear as i thought it should.
i tried to add any div with a class, span with class. but they also don't work at all.

Only work if i put a tag for viewing text like P, H1 H2 (all heading tag).
And its hard for me to put an image or animated content if the only tag that work is for showing Text

could someone help me to find what i probably missed at the code?

Comment: For better performance, you should put your script tags just inside the closing body tag, not in the head.

Comment: What `tab-img` class does acually? and you are not defining it in CSS also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your jquery you're using the selector as `$('#tabs div')`.

What this means is all the `div` children (and their children) of `#tabs` will be hidden and that's why your class `tab-img` isn't working. You can make the selector `$('#tabs > div')` which only searches for divs that have `#tab` as a parent.

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/kvkZX/1/

Comment: I updated your fiddle to show more clearly how not only `.tab-img` is displaying correctly but is showing the correct `.tab-img` for the given tab.